# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, youtube

I have a page with multiple YouTube embedded players that I need to listen for events on. I am trying to use the solution posted as the answer to  [Using Youtube's javascript API with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786380/using-youtubes-javascript-api-with-jquery), but I am getting a strange error: (in Chrome 18.0.1025.137 beta-m)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %
```

That is the extent of the error, including stacktrace. My code is like this:

```
var onYouTubePlayerReady = function (id) {
var evt = '(function(){})';

alert(eval(evt)); //just to verify that the snippet is syntactically correct

var ytplayer = document.getElementById(id);
ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", evt);
};
```

(see the other question for more context)

The error is thrown when the `onStateChange` event is fired. If I make `evt` `""` or a function name, then it doesn't throw the error (but I also get no state information).

Clearly, the error message is bogus, but anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible?

Comment: Make sure that you are getting response by doing something like this - `var evt = '(function(state){ alert(state); })';`

Comment: @Diode: I tried that, but see my answer to find out the real problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, turns out it's incredibly stupid. Running the code in Firefox yielded a real error message:

```
syntax error


try { __flash__toXML(%28function%28%29%7B%7D%29(5)) ; } catch (e) { "<undefined/...
---------------------^
```

So, apparently, it needs to be serializable to XML in order to be used as a callback. Which is really kind of annoying.

My solution was something like this:

```
var ytCallbackID = 1;

var makeYTCallback = function (func) {
    var ret = "ytCallback" + (ytCallbackID++);
    window[ret] = func;

    return ret;
}

var onYouTubePlayerReady = function (id) {
    var evt = makeYTCallback(function(state) {
        onYouTubePlayerStateChange(id, state);
    });

    var ytplayer = document.getElementById(id);
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", evt);
};
```

<del>I haven't fully tested it (since I did this right at the end of the day yesterday), but I think it'll work.</del>

Got around to testing it, and it works like a charm! It's a bit fugly, both in idea and implementation, but it works and that's what's important :)